# JavaFX Polygon пересечение

Tags: java, javafx, разработка-игр

есть два корабля. у них есть хитбоксы в виде полигонов. (корабли могут вращаться Bounds не катят).

Мой способ поиска пересечений: 
проверить на вхождение в полигон противника родных точек. и наоборот. 
из-за этого могут возникнуть ситуации, когда пересечение есть, но вершины не пересекают чужие хитбоксы. Как с этим бороться?

есть какие-то более адекватные алгоритмы поиска пересечения полигонов?